# How to make a link remember what value it had as an href before transferring to be used in the next page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

With research, I was able to come up with a neat way to display information in my database into a php page.

Now my next aim is to link each row to another php page that will recognize what account ID the user has clicked

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Account ID</th>
<th>Account Username</th>
<th>Account Password</th>

<th>Account First Name</th>
<th>Account Middle Name</th>
<th>Account Last Name</th>

<th>Account Phase</th>
<th>Account Block - Lot</th>
<th>Account Subdivision</th>

<th>Account Contact Number</th>
<th>Account Email Address</th>
<th>Account Status</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_user'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_pass'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['acc_fname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_mname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_lname'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['acc_phase'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_blk-lot'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_subd'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['acc_contact_num'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_email_address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_status'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I tried this `echo "<td><a href='target php page here'>" . $row['acc_no'] . "</td>"` but all the links generated will have the same value. I think JQuery might be needed for this or something but unfortunately, this stuff is not yet taught in our school or there might be a better work around for my problem. please help.

Comment: just a place holder for now

Comment: I don't know PHP, but it should be something like: `echo "<td><a href='/accounts/". $row['id']."'>" . $row['acc_no'] . "</td>"`

Comment: @dimakura, what you are suggesting means that there should be specific page for each account. Im looking for a way that when the admin transfers to the target php page, he can have the selected `$row['acc_no']` information to be manipulated

Comment: @MattYoü If you have links like `/accounts/1` , `/accounts/2` and so on, what's your problem to extract `id=1` and `id=2` part on dedicated page?

Comment: There could be a page for each specific account - just have the page accept inputs to manipulate the account. If you don't like that, have the link point to itself with a query string added to it: (`?id=$row['acc_no']`) and put fields there. jQuery would only be useful here if you want to do stuff with ajax - which seems like it would be too complicated for you right now.

Comment: @HPierce, sir can you elaborate the workaround about the query string. I am going to google it right now. So does this mean that in the link will know what `acc_no` the user clicked from the previous page?

Comment: @MattYoü, basically - yes. [This site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm) gives an ok explanation, pay special attention to `$_GET`

Comment: @HPierce, sir. I am quite familiar with the $_GETand $_POST but I am not sure how to integrate the logic inside a While loop, I mean as long as the loop is not finished, does this mean the $_GET or $_POST will loop with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure how to integrate the logic inside a While loop, I mean
>   as long as the loop is not finished, does this mean the $_GET or
>   $_POST will loop with it?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
// Step 1.
// Create a custom URL that points to this same script, 
// passing the account number as a $_GET parameter.
echo '<td><a href="thisScript.php?id=' . $row['acc_no'] . '">' . $row['acc_no'] . "</a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_user'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_pass'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['acc_fname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_mname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_lname'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['acc_phase'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_blk-lot'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_subd'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['acc_contact_num'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_email_address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['acc_status'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

// Step 2.
// Check if the user has already clicked a one of the URLs we custom made in step 1.
if (isset($_GET['id'] && $_GET['id'] == $row['acc_no']){
     // the user has, so let's allow them to change the fields.
     // This form appears directly under the record that was clicked.
     echo '<form action="commitChangesScript.php" method="post">';
     echo '<input type="text" name="fname">';
     //repeat for any fields you want to be able the change.
     // ...
     echo '</form>';
}
}
```

First create the custom URLs, this can be done without a form by simply creating a link to the location with a query string at the end of it.

On the first page load, `isset($_GET['id']` will never be true, because the user presumably hasn't selected an account yet. The first page load create the table as well as all the links for specific users. The URLs are unique because they are created using the account number. For account #1, the URL is pointed at thisScript.php?id=1, for account #987 the URL is thisSciprt.php?id=987.

When the user selects an account number, a new form appears allowing them to change fields. This works because `$_GET['id']` will be set to the account number that was selected. We can compare that input with the field in the DB allowing all other rows not to have the form.

This is just an example of what would work. The form included would interrupt the `<table>` which might look kind of gross.

> does this mean the $_GET or $_POST will loop with it?

$_GET and $_POST are defined outside of the `while`, meaning they will not be repeatedly defined. They are however, within scope inside the `while` loop as demonstrated in the example I've shown.